# Dynamic Width Measurement: ReactJS/NodeJS & HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I am writing a personal home page, and am interested in the appraised google card design as follows: [image]

As You can see on the bottom card, the underline/footer/divider does not quite meet the end of the text as it should, due to it having a preset width in my css file. Sure I could just write multiple classes for each card (I have a total of 5), but that is not only tedious but messy too. I was wondering if there was a way for me too measure the width of the text and insert said width as the width of the footer/divider. Links to articles/questions are appreciated as much as any other answer. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. Unless there is a great reason not to - I'd use the CSS property for underline

```
 text-decoration: underline;
```